# Select the producs of a provider with the lower product

Tags: sql, oracle

i have two tables, products and provider

Provider:

```
nif
user
```

Products:

```
cod_prod
name
price
provider
stock
```

Expected Result:

for example we have in the table products this;

| cod_prod | name | Price | Provid | Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ball | 2.00 | peter | 20 |
| 2 | shoe | 1.00 | peter | 20 |
| 3 | flower | 3.00 | peter | 20 |
| 4 | bag | 7.00 | peter | 20 |
| 5 | balloon | 3.00 | peter | 20 |
| 6 | gun | 2.00 | martin | 20 |
| 7 | shotgun | 4.00 | martin | 20 |
| 8 | cheese | 7.00 | martin | 20 |
| 9 | shirt | 7.00 | martin | 20 |
| 10 | sunglass | 6.00 | martin | 20 |

in this scenario the product with the lower price is the shoe,

2       shoe  1.00 peter     40

What i want if that after the query get this result of the lower product price,
i get this result:

```
   name  provider 
   ball   peter     
   shoe   peter     
 flower   peter     
    bag   peter     
balloon   peter
```

Because the query after selecting the lower product price, get all the products from the provider with the low product price.

i have this query at the moment

```
select provider.user, products.name from provider
inner join products
on provider.nif = products.provider
where products.price = (select min(products.price) from products);
```

With this i can select the most cheap item, but i do not know how to resolve, the thing is that i want a query that with the condition of the lowest cheap item i can get the list of products of that provider.

P.D: I updated the question with the expected result and examples of the product table to be more specific about what i want to obtain.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want.

Comment: i updated the expected result, for clarification about what i want to do with this query :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option; it ranks products per price and then uses that CTE (`rank_them`) to fetch data you're interested in.

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  provider (nif, cuser) as
  4    (select 1, 'Provider 1' from dual union all
  5     select 2, 'Provider 2' from dual
  6    ),
  7  products (cod_prod, name, price, provider) as
  8    (select 1, 'Sugar', 10, 1 from dual union all
  9     select 2, 'Milk' , 20, 1 from dual union all
 10     select 3, 'Salt' ,  5, 2 from dual union all   --> cheapest
 11     select 4, 'Water', 15, 2 from dual
 12    ),
 13  -- query begins here
 14  rank_them as
 15    (select p.*,
 16          rank() over (order by price) rnk
 17     from products p
 18    )
 19  select d.nif, d.cuser, r.cod_prod, r.name, r.price
 20  from rank_them r join provider d on d.nif = r.provider
 21  where r.provider = (select r1.provider
 22                      from rank_them r1
 23                      where r1.rnk = 1
 24                     );

       NIF CUSER        COD_PROD NAME       PRICE
---------- ---------- ---------- ----- ----------
         2 Provider 2          3 Salt           5
         2 Provider 2          4 Water         15

SQL>
```

Comment: Including line numbers with the code is just mean ;)

Comment: That's copy/paste of my SQL*Plus session, @Mat. I didn't mean to be mean (maybe just a little bit) :)